# python parallel map (multiprocessing.Pool.map) with global data

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I'm trying to call a function on multiple processes.  The obvious solution is python's `multiprocessing` module.  The problem is that the function has side effects.  It creates a temporary file and registers that file to be deleted on exit using the `atexit.register` and a global list.  The following should demonstrate the problem (in a different context).

```
import multiprocessing as multi

glob_data=[]
def func(a):
    glob_data.append(a)

map(func,range(10))
print glob_data  #[0,1,2,3,4 ... , 9]  Good.

p=multi.Pool(processes=8)
p.map(func,range(80))

print glob_data  #[0,1,2,3,4, ... , 9] Bad, glob_data wasn't updated.
```

Is there any way to have the global data updated?

Note that if you try out the above script, you probably shouldn't try it from the interactive interpreter since `multiprocessing` requires the module `__main__` to be importable by child processes.

**UPDATE**

Added the `global` keyword in func doesn't help -- e.g.:

```
def func(a):  #Still doesn't work.
    global glob_data
    glob_data.append(a)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need the list `glob_data` to be backed by shared memory, Multiprocessing's Manager gives you just that:

```
import multiprocessing as multi
from multiprocessing import Manager

manager = Manager()

glob_data = manager.list([])

def func(a):
    glob_data.append(a)

map(func,range(10))
print glob_data  # [0,1,2,3,4 ... , 9] Good.

p = multi.Pool(processes=8)
p.map(func,range(80))

print glob_data # Super Good.
```

For some background:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#managers

Comment: Cheers, this works perfectly for me.  I should mention here that it works because the objects that I am appending to glob_data are immutable (ints in the example, strings in my actual application).  If they objects being packed into the list are mutable, then care must be taken to re-add them to the list if they are changed.

Comment: @RafaelFerreira   Works well ! but the results aren't consistent, like in my case.. am using manager.dict(), values change each time I run my code. I see that lock should be applied but not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Have func return a tuple with the results you want from the processing and the thing you want to append to glob_data. Then, when the p.map has completed, you can extract the results from the first elements in the returned tuples and you can build glob_data from the second elements.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that ... My use-case is a little more complicated than that however.  The temporary files that I want to delete are buried deep inside classes and since they are only temporary files, I prefer to keep them and their names as a private part of the class API (Implementation detail) ...